# Raspberry Pi Zero W: Can't restart Wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I've read several threads out there regarding Raspbian WiFi connectivity problems.
I've solved many of my problems, but I'm not figuring out why (or how?) I can't restart WiFi.

Upon reboot, **WiFi is connected fine**, I just can't manually restart it.

## The Problem

`$ sudo ifdown wlan0`

```
ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured
```

`$ sudo ifup wlan0 --force -v`

```
ifup: reading directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
ifup: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/lo
ifup: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0

ifup: configuring interface wlan0=wlan0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
ifup: failed to bring up wlan0
```

After reading some of the logs I found that there are state files in `/var/run/network/ifstate.wlan0` and `/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0`.

Is this correct? Perhaps in `wpa_supplicant.conf` file I'm pointing `ctrl_interface` to the wrong place?
What are the different purposes of those two different `wlan0` state files?

What is the correct way to restart networking without reboot?

## My Configurations:

`$ ifconfig -a`

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Loopback Local)
    RX packets 400  bytes 118100 (115.3 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 400  bytes 118100 (115.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::e9c2:462e:7e58:2755  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether b8:27:eb:81:62:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 5027  bytes 6582631 (6.2 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2057  bytes 273735 (267.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`$ iwconfig wlan0`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MySSID"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 84:16:F9:FC:36:54   
      Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-28 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

`$ cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="MySSID"
    psk="MyPassword"
}
```

`$ cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

`$ ls -la /etc/network/interfaces.d`

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 set 25 17:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 set 25 15:15 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31 ago 31 19:44 lo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   95 set 25 15:10 wlan0
```

`$ cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/lo`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`$ cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0`

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless-power off
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: I don't know what your problem is (or even if it is due to the Pi) **BUT** I do know that filling your configuration files with collections of stuff you found on the web is only going to make it worse. In particular `dhcp` will disable the default network manager `dhcpcd` and decrease robustness. Put the settings back to those in [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
which work for everyone else. THEN explain WHY you think "WiFi is off"

Comment: Well, manual addresses is not common in a *normal* network scenario. I thought that the dhcp option is to let the network router assign the ip as it does to every other device on his network. Why should I assign a static address? If I have 10 RPis on the same network with dozens of other devices, that becomes impractical to maintain. I have a static ip assigned by the router, but I don't agree that the device should specify it's own IP as the normal scenario.

Comment: @Milliways if neither `dhcp` and `manual` configurations are adequate for my scenario, what other option there is?

Comment: I did not suggest static - manual lets the network manager handle DHCP rather than your (incorrect) use of dhcp

Comment: In fact if you delete the 'interfaces' file it will just work

Answer (score 2):

On the Pi Zero W, what worked for me was the sequence of:

`sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`

(no delay or polling required between those)

For my purposes I was able to do it on one line as:
`sudo ifconfig wlan0 down; sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`

I know it has been a while since it was asked, but this was a long standing frustration for me, as I had reverted to using a Pi B which seems to accept all common suggestions in other posts.

I hope this one does it for you!